# VB Razor (*.VBHTML) IntelliSense isn't working with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, razor, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2019 `*.vbhtml` files were working fine in my computer. After upgrading to Visual Studio 2022, C# IntelliSense and highlighting are still working, but in VB IntelliSense and highlighting fully disappear.

Also, any attempt at adding VB templates (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design) became forbidden.

[image: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design]

Is there a way to bypass these restrictions and unblock VB in Razor Pages with some tuning of Visual Studio or with some extension for Visual Studio or with some 3rd party product?

Comment: Razor Pages aren't supported in VB beyond MVC5. Did you change the project's target framework?

Comment: @InteXX Currently my project target framework NET CORE 6. VB Razor pages was working perfectly in any NET version with VS2019. I have updates VS today and new VS2022 full freeze where faced VBHTML file. Before updating previous version opened this file perfectly, but without intellisense, last version of Visual Studio can open ANY file in text mode - except *.VBHTML.

Comment: I no longer have VS 2019 installed, so I'm unable to test your earlier scenario at my location. FYI have a look at [Vazor](https://github.com/VBAndCs/Vazor). It works pretty well and it supports .NET Core 6.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor Pages are no longer supported in VB.NET after MVC5. As noted, editing and compilation (without IntelliSense) did work under Visual Studio 2019, but that functionality has been removed in Visual Studio 2022.

A working alternative for MVC and Razor Page projects in VB.NET under .NET Core 6 is Vazor, which can be found [here](https://github.com/VBAndCs/Vazor).

Answer (score 0):

My final solution you can see there https://github.com/Alex-1557/SplitViewAndCodeInAsp.Net.Core.Project/tree/main

Yes, have I lost opportunity to use VB in View and VBHTML, but I receive opportunity to split ASP.NET Core project to 2 full different projects.

[image]

For connect static files to root I have rebuilded this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CeciliaWiren-CeciliaSHARP.FolderToSolutionFolder

for Visual Studio 2022 - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexev14.AddFolderToSolutionForVS2022